# .NET xmldatasource doesn't show latest data on postback

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, lifecycle, data-binding

I've run into a problem that I'm at a loss to understand and/or work around.

I'm working on a settings page that updates an XML file.  The page has an XmlDataSource with a transform file (to filter and sort the values) and a DataList that is populated from the XmlDataSource.  A user can enter a new group name into a text box and click a button to submit the form.  When this happens, the new value is successfully added to the XML file.

So I've got a simple situation: post the form and update the data source.  Of course, I'd also like the DataList to show the newly added value, but I seem to have run out of luck there.  The new value does not show up right away.  If I immediately enter another value and submit the form, the value that I had entered previously will show up.  In effect, I'm one step behind every time the form is submitted.

Here is the markup:

```
<asp:DataList ID="list_groups" runat="server" DataSourceID="siteConfig_supportGroups"
 CellSpacing="0" EnableViewState="False">
<ItemTemplate>
    <div style="margin-bottom:12px;">            
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/del.png"
         CommandArgument='<%#Eval("name") %>' style="float:left; margin-right:6px;" />
        &nbsp;<%#Eval("name")%>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>

New: <asp:TextBox ID="txt_new_group" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
<asp:Button ID="btn_new_group" runat="server" Text="Add" />

<asp:XmlDataSource ID="siteConfig_supportGroups" runat="server" 
 DataFile="~/presets.xml"  EnableViewState="False" EnableCaching="False" 
 TransformFile="supportGroups.xslt"></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

And the code, all contained in the event handler for the button click:

```
Dim presets As New XmlDocument
presets.Load(Server.MapPath("presets.xml"))

Dim newNode As XmlNode = presets.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "group", Nothing)
Dim nodeName As XmlAttribute = presets.CreateAttribute("name")
nodeName.Value = txt_new_group.Text

newNode.Attributes.Append(nodeName)

Dim test As XmlNode = presets.SelectSingleNode("settings/supportGroups")
test.AppendChild(newNode)

presets.Save(Server.MapPath("presets.xml"))
```

In terms of page lifecycle and data binding, I am not aware of any problems with this setup.  My understanding is that the data binding occurs at or after the prerender event, which definitely comes after the code above.  That leads me to think that there might be something funky going on with the xml file itself.  Perhaps it's read by the XmlDataSource control before my code has a chance to make updates and save it?

Most of the searching that I've done mentions using the XmlDataSource's getXmlDocument() method, which returns an xmlDocument that can be edited and saved through the XmlDataSource's save() method.  However, I get an error that states the save method cannot be used while a transform file has been specified.  I need the transform file to sort the options for the user.  Everything else mentions the enableviewstate and enablecaching attributes, which don't fix the problem either.

Any insights or workaround suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed a few things that got the page working.

First of all, the data update problems went away when I took the ImageButton out of the DataList's template.  I have no idea why this made a difference, but it did.

As an alternative, I tried to use a Repeater which included the ImageButton in the template and the ViewState disabled.  This worked - the data was updated whenever a new value was added.  However, I had to reenable ViewState so that the server would catch the ItemCommand event.  This put the data out of sync again.  To fix that, I added a databind operation right after the xml file is updated.

Everything now works!  When a new value is added, the repeater shows the new value, and when the imagebutton is clicked, the server picks up the ItemCommand event.  Best of all, I didn't have to mess around with the XmlDataSource and transform file that I had set up.

Final Markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="siteConfig_supportGroups">
<ItemTemplate>
<div style="margin-bottom:12px;">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="~/Images/del.png" runat="server" 
     CommandArgument='<%#Eval("name") %>' />
    &nbsp;<%#Eval("name")%>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

New: <asp:TextBox ID="txt_new_group" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
<asp:Button ID="btn_new_group" runat="server" Text="Add" />

<asp:XmlDataSource ID="siteConfig_supportGroups" runat="server"
 DataFile="~/presets.xml"  EnableViewState="False" EnableCaching="False"
 TransformFile="~/supportGroups.xslt" ></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

Final Code:

```
Private Sub btn_new_group_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
   Handles btn_new_group.Click
    Dim presets As New XmlDocument
    presets.Load(Server.MapPath("presets.xml"))

    Dim newNode As XmlNode = presets.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "group", Nothing)
    Dim nodeName As XmlAttribute = presets.CreateAttribute("name")
    nodeName.Value = txt_new_group.Text

    newNode.Attributes.Append(nodeName)

    Dim test As XmlNode = presets.SelectSingleNode("settings/supportGroups")
    test.AppendChild(newNode)

    presets.Save(Server.MapPath("presets.xml"))

    Repeater1.DataBind()
    txt_new_group.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub Repeater1_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs) 
   Handles Repeater1.ItemCommand
    Dim test = "Hey!"
End Sub
```